# sdiff - limit the result set to X items

Tags: redis

I want to get the diff of two sets in redis, but I don't need to return the entire array, just 10 items for example.  Is there any way to limit the results?

I was thinking something like this:

`SDIFF set1 set2 LIMIT 10`

If not, are there any other options to achieve this in a performant way, considering that set1 can be millions of objects and set2 is much much smaller (hundreds).

Comment: what about `SDIFFSTORE` and then executing `SRANDMEMBER` with count ?

Answer (score 0):

More info would be helpful on what you want to achieve. Something like this **might** require you to duplicate your data. Though I don’t know if it’s something you want.

An option is chunking them.

1. Create a set with a unique generated id that can hold a max of 10 items
2. Create a sorted set like so…

`zadd(key, timestamp, chunkid)`

where your timestamp is a unix time and the chunkid is the key the connects to the set. The key can be the name of whatever you would like it to be or it could also be a uniquely generated id.

3. Use zrange to grab a specific one

(Repeat steps 1-3 for the second set)

4. Once you have your 1 result from both your sorted sets “zset”. You can now do your sdiff by using the chunkid.

Note that there is advantages and disadvantages in doing this. Like more connection consumption (if calling from a a client), and the obvious being a little more processing. Though it will help immensely if you put this in a lua script.

Hope this helps or at least gives you an idea on how to model your data. Though if this is critical data you might need to use a automated script of some sort to move your data around to meet the modeling requirement.